# foreach loop only echos last item, but all items elements are being shown in Vardump

Tags: php, foreach

I am changing product IDs when inventory is 0. In the following code these are product IDs - 1308, 1309, 1310

```html
function btn_shortcode(){
    
$link_url = array (1308, 1309, 1310);
    foreach ($link_url as $pr_id) {
        $increment = 0;
        $productt = wc_get_product( $pr_id);
        $qty2 = $productt->get_stock_quantity();
        if($qty2 <= 0) continue;
        if($increment == 1)return;  
            $increment++;   
            
            var_dump ($pr_id);
}

$url = "http://localhost/wordpress/product/22q2-prime-";


 ?>

    <form class="cart" action="<?php echo $url . $pr_id; ?>" method="post">

        <div class="quantity">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_6332f81bdfee0">22Q2 - Prime - 2 quantity</label>
        <div class="bs-quantity">
        <div class="qty-nav">
        <div class="quantity-button quantity-down limit">-</div>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity_6332f81bdfee0" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="2" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="22Q2 - Prime - 2 quantity">
        <div class="qty-nav">
        <div class="quantity-button quantity-up ">+</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="12" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Join Now</button>

    </form>

        
        
        
<?php
 
}


add_shortcode('sc_btn','btn_shortcode');
```

When the inventory is 0, the loop is catching the next product ID and returning value. I am changing the action of button dynamically or changing URLs when inventory is 0. But the foreach loop always echos the last item. It's always showing the value of this product ID "1310" and not movinf from first. I have used same code in different place which is working fine. But it's not working while using in button's action. Would like to have your suggestions.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it will return $pr_id will be the last id. If you want to echo all the ids in the form action, then you have to end your loop after the form.

```
function btn_shortcode(){
    
$link_url = array (1308, 1309, 1310);
    foreach ($link_url as $pr_id) {
        $increment = 0;
        $productt = wc_get_product( $pr_id);
        $qty2 = $productt->get_stock_quantity();
        if($qty2 <= 0) continue;
        if($increment == 1)return;  
            $increment++;   
            
            var_dump ($pr_id);
$url = "http://localhost/wordpress/product/22q2-prime-";


 ?>

    <form class="cart" action="<?php echo $url . $pr_id; ?>" method="post">

        <div class="quantity">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_6332f81bdfee0">22Q2 - Prime - 2 quantity</label>
        <div class="bs-quantity">
        <div class="qty-nav">
        <div class="quantity-button quantity-down limit">-</div>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity_6332f81bdfee0" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="2" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="22Q2 - Prime - 2 quantity">
        <div class="qty-nav">
        <div class="quantity-button quantity-up ">+</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="12" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Join Now</button>

    </form>

        
        
        
<?php
 } //End of loop
}


add_shortcode('sc_btn','btn_shortcode');
```